# lineplot not giving the desired results

Tags: python, pandas, line-plot

| Scenarios | Node-0 | Node-1 | Node-2 | Node-3 | Node-4 | Node-5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Original System | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Leak_Node_1 | 1 | 0.043 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0043 |
| Leak_Node_2 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.012 |
| Leak_Node_3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0086 |
| Leak_Node_4 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0085 |
| Leak_Node_5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.0076 |

How do I get the exact kind of line plot in the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19_RVA9t7YvarTmc4W1Im2DtqevHvvZG0/view?usp=sharing

I tried using the code below:
`pi1.plot.line()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to set 'Scenarios' as index in the dataframe and transpose it before plotting.

```py
pi1.set_index('Scenarios').transpose().plot.line()
```

It should give you this results:
[image: resulting plot with transposed dataframe]

*Note:* If you need to match the colors too (since you stated exactly), use the `color` argument of `df.plot.line()` (see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html))

Answer (score 1):

You have to transpose you DataFrame, because pandas evaluates columns and in your example the figure plots the rows.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
t="""Scenarios  Node-0  Node-1  Node-2  Node-3  Node-4  Node-5
Original System     1   1   1   1   1   1
Leak_Node_1     1   0.043   1   1   1   0.0043
Leak_Node_2     1   1   1   1   1   0.012
Leak_Node_3     1   1   1   1   1   0.0086
Leak_Node_4     1   1   1   1   1   0.0085
Leak_Node_5     1   1   1   1   1   0.0076"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(t), sep='\s\s+', index_col=0, engine='python')
df.T.plot.line()
```

[image: Result]